# Example where Manhattan/CityBlock-distance is used to generate recommendations?

Tags: distance, mahout, recommendation-engine

when creating a neighborhood based recommender,there are various distance-measures available (e.g. in Apache Mahout) and I can find quite some practical examples for most of them. But I never stumbled over examples where the Manhattan distance (a.k.a city block distance) outperformed others.

I'd be happy to find some ;)

Comment: It isn't that city block isn't useful, its just that changing similarities is more of a tweak rather than anything else.

Comment: That's what it seems like, but then I wonder why Apache Mahout has an implementation for it...

Comment: So that you can tweak your recommendation output. Mahout isn't known for its scientific application but rather how well it can scale.

Comment: But that was the question, if there are no real usecases where Manhattan-distance is "good", why would it help to improve the recommendation output?

Comment: It might just perform better for your particular dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manhattan distance is rarely useful; it's there mostly for completeness. It might be useful in cases where your ratings are really discrete values like counts, and it has some relation to edit distance, so might be useful if the items were... strings. But that's probably not a real use case for recommenders.